# SoundPlayer won't work with a string

Tags: c#, audio

Okay so i'm a noob, and spent 4 hours on Google already. So i would really appreciate some help. I'm trying to play a sound with a variable (got 100+ sounds) And i have done everything in this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17422/Embedding-and-Playing-WAV-Audio-Files-in-a-WinForm

This works:

`System.Media.SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer
(PROGRAM.Properties.Resources.audio);
soundPlayer.Play();`

This Doesn't work:

`string file = "PROGRAM.Properties.Resources.audio";`

`System.Media.SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer
(file);
soundPlayer.Play();`

ERROR: Please be sure a sound file exists at the specified location... System.Media:SoundPlayer.ValidateSoundFile(StringfileName)

How is it possible that the string doesn't work?

Comment: For the SoundPlayer constructor that accepts a string, it must either be a file path or a URL to a .wav file; `PROGAM.Properties.Resources.Audio` is an instance member inside of your `PROGRAM` namespace that cannot be represented by a string.

Comment: But i wan't to embedd the wav files in the project. How can i play embedded files with a variable? I can't be that hard right?

Comment: If you read the tutorial you provided above, it details how to add resources such as .wav files into your project (see the section entitled "Adding Audio Files to Resources") - also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I have already embedded the audio files. But i can't firure out how to acces them with SoundPlayer without typing <My Project>.Properties.Resources.<My audio file> Directly. A soon as i try to use a variable i just get errors. I just want a simple code to play a wav files via a variable, so that i can play differant sounds.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `PROGRAM.Properties.Resources.audio` in the first example, you're actually getting a reference to a stream (which gives you the embedded audio data). This is managed by the auto-generated code your .resx produces.

When you pass `"PROGRAM.Properties.Resources.audio"` as a string, the SoundPlayer interprets that as a file name, and then obviously can't find it.

If you want to manually get the audio stream from a resource file, try:

```
var stream = PROGRAM.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream( "audio" );
var soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer( stream );
soundPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch Chris! Works perfecly.